# How to call ENDCMTCTL with pending changes?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rollback, crash-recovery

My iSeries ILE program crashed with uncommitted changes. 
Now I wish to end commitment control (to start program again, program starts commitment control itself) with ENDCMTCTL, but it fails with message:

```
CPF8355 - ENDCMTCTL not allowed. Pending changes active
```

Is there a way to rollback/commit changes and end commitment control proper way? My more experienced colleagues suggest only to sign out and start new session.

**Edit**

I have tried WRKCMTDFN and all actions in it with no success. 
Force rollback and Force commit failed with message:

```
CPD83ED -Commitment definition not eligible for forced rollback ... 
... 2 -- The logical unit of work, for this commitment definition, is not in
an undecided state.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message ID is probably CPF8355, and the second level text is helpful to understand the situation:

```
 Cause . . . . . :   An attempt was made to end commitment control for         
   commitment definition &1. However, there are one or more active resources   
   under commitment control for the commitment definition. The resources could 
   be one of the following:                                                    
     -- Local files                                                            
     -- Remote files                                                           
     -- API commitment resources                                               
     -- Remote SQL database
```

Use WRKJOB OPTION(*CMTCTL) to see which resources are still open and under commitment control.  If there are open files, the program should close them before trying ENDCMTCTL.  If this is a case where there are repeated CALLs to an RPG program which leaves files open for performance reasons, CALL it one last time with a special parameter which will tell it to close the files.  Alternatively, if it's an ILE program, consider RCLACTGRP.

Comment: RCLACTGRP works partially. I have to close IDE we use (TURNOVER) to reclaim activation group. After RCLACTGRP, state remains inconsistent and another invocation of program fails in system - `MCH3402 - Tried to refer to all or part of an object that no longer exists`. So like @Benny said ending job seems only valid option.

Comment: I thought Turnover was a change management system, but I don't use it.  Are you calling your program from within Turnover?  That might be adding to the confusion.  Call your program from a command line and see if it'll work with a RCLACTGRP.

Comment: My mistake, not IDE! Same behavior when running from command line

Comment: OK so it seems there is also a service program in the reclaimed AG.  Can you put the problem program in a separate, named activation group and then reclaim only that AG?

Comment: Separate activation group works well - no more problems after RCLACTGRP. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

After [reading the documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/cl/endcmtctl.htm) it appears there is not much else you can do. I would have expected you to be presented with an option to commit changes or roll them back based on this:

> If there are uncommitted changes for an interactive job, a message is
>   sent asking the user whether the changes should be committed or rolled
>   back before a commitment definition is ended. For a batch job, the
>   changes are rolled back.

Because you did not get this option I think your job has already begun the commit (or roll back) process and you cannot change it at this point. So you're left with the sole "option" of logging off - which will end your job and associated commitment control.

Comment: Yes it looks like commit/rollback process already started, i have modified question with some details

Comment: @Piro - I think at this point all you can do is terminate your job (sign off the session, ENDJOB, whatever). It sounds like the commit/rollback has already happened but some resource hasn't closed yet - something like the scenario Buck describes with a file being left open in an RPG program where LR isn't turned on.